# Why is the new value not set when I exit the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I simplified the problem I had in my application as follows. Even if I enter a new word in the `TextInput`, when I go back in the page it says `"initial"`. Why doesn't it write new value?

Actually, what I want to do here is to send the last entered text to redux as soon as I press the phone's back button(hardwareBackPress). But it always sends the initial value. How can I solve this problem?

```
import { TextInput } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function ChangeModel({ navigation }) {
    const [text, setText] = useState("initial")
  
    const onPressSave = () => {
        console.log(text)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => onPressSave()
    }, [])


    return (
        <TextInput
            value={text}
            onChangeText={setText}
            style={{ backgroundColor: "grey" }}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: where are you trying to save the value _to_?

Comment: @DanielA.White to the redux

Comment: not seeing you use redux here.

Comment: @DanielA.White I didn't add it because what I'm asking here is that the new text value cannot appear. I added the redux codes to the answer now

Comment: It's a not-so-runnable snippet. :(

Comment: @Wyck Yes, because Daniel made an unnecessary request and left without solving it even though I did what he said. I edited the question again. You can now run :)

Comment: @Nemesis have **you** tried clicking the _Run code snippet_ button?

Answer (score -2):

you're not set anything that makes the value change, try to set the state with new value:

```
setText(newValue)
```

if you handle with `redux` you should import the `action` first and `dispatch` it after that

Answer (score -2):

To get entered data you have to write a button component like this

```
import { TextInput, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function ChangeModel({ navigation }) {
const [text, setText] = useState('initial');

const onPressSave = () => {
 console.log(text);
};

useEffect(() => {
 return () => onPressSave();
}, []);

return (
 <View>
   <TextInput value={text} onChangeText={setText} />
   <Button title="Press me" onPress={onPressSave} />
 </View>
 );
 }
```

When you click the button on the back of the phone, the state is default